# accessing files in custom folder in wordpress

Tags: filesystem

after uploading files in a custom folder "myuploads" using PHP code, I want to show these files in admin. This folder resides in the root directory along with wp-admin,wp-content,wp-includes folder. I have also tried links like "/myuploads/filename" or "../myuploads/filename" in admin but both give

"oops! that page cannot be accessed error".

I am new to wordpress so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where in admin would you like to show them?

Comment: I have a page which shows the list of records and within that list I wanted to add a link to these files. `<a href="../myuploads/filename.docx">download</a>` does not work. 
I also tried using PHP download file code but I guess the link is not supported like above in admin as the file downloaded using custom PHP code is blank